# Android apache Poi ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I developed an Android application (I am a beginner), but I have a problem with a ArrayAdapater.

I used an Array adapter in the first part of my code and there are no errors :

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrList);
        testSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But on the rest of the code there is an error for the creation of the second array adapter :

```
testSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
             public void  onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
             {
                 String var = arrList.get(pos);

                 if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals(var))
                 {
                     ArrayList<String> arrListA = arrList2.get(pos);

                     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrListA); //error

                     testSpinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
                     System.out.println(var);
                 }
             }});
```

Eclipse said for the error : " The constructor ArrayAdapter(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){},int,Array List) is Undefined "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because your 'this' operator points to `new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()` (the new listener you created). To fix this replace with: `<YourClassName>.this`.

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to do but decalring the new adpater in the listener is not a very good idea. It would be better to just initialize it over there.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the text in angular parenthesis was not displayed. Fixed now.